# Having problems with mysql deprecated(not mysqli)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using mysql deprecated (not mysqli), and when I try to log in it have errors which are:

> Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link 
>          resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\booking system\login_user.php on line 18
>
> Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result
>          resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\booking system\login_user.php on line 20

here is the code :

```
<?php

    session_start();

    //connect to database
    include("dbconnectlogin.php");
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("logindb");

if (isset($_POST['login'])){

    $employeeNo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['employeeNo']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $password = md5('&password');//remember we hashedpassword before storing last time

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM loginT WHERE employeeNo = '$employeeNo' AND password = '$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
    {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "You are now logged in";
        $_SESSION['employeeNo'] = $employeeNo;
        header("location:mainpage.php");
    }

    else{

        $_SESSION['message'] = "Username or password in incorrect";     
    }
}

?>
```

Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: add your code. mysql_query($connection, $query); Here first variable should be connection object and second should be your query string.

Comment: why continue to use that api? Upgrade to mysqli and save yourself some heartache

Comment: The old mysql_ was ***REMOVED*** from PHP 7, so if you end up on a server running PHP 7.x your site/app will break

Comment: i don't know..the place that i'm doing internship right now haven't upgraded yet. So, it is killing me.. -_-''

Comment: Rohit Mittal.. tried but still the same..

Comment: I'm using PHP 5..I had to downgraded the PHP...huaaa

Comment: you should assign a variable to `mysql_connect` - ie: `$db=mysql_connect(.....)` and then use that variable in other db calls. This line `$password = md5('&password');` is puzzling though - it will always override whatever the user enters into the form and submits..

Comment: @RamRaider well the errors are gone. But, when i try again, the page is blank. thank you for help.

Comment: where does the script get to ? add some debug statements to find what breaks or look in the php error log file

Comment: **Don't use `md5()` for password hashing.** It's very insecure. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. Since you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5, you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: If possible, I would recommend finding a new place to do your internship if they are still on PHP 5.1. That version hit it's end of life 12 years ago. :-o

Comment: The second argument here is optional `$result = mysql_query($sql, $db);` and you never defined `$db`.

Comment: PHP 5 doesn't get security updates any more. You really should upgrade away from it instead of trying to fix code using features that depend on it.

Comment: just for fun give us the url of the site }-)

Answer (score 2):

The second argument is optional

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
```

And `$db` is undefined.

> Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\booking system\login_user.php on line 18

Which makes sense because `$db` is undefined, which is the resource link.

If you really want to put it in (such as connecting to 2 DB's) you can capture the resource when you do `mysql_connect`

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("logindb", $db);
```

Otherwise PHP will keep track of it "magically" and you can remove it from the query part.

```
//without defining $db
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Man it's been about 7 years sense I coded with `mysql_*`, those were the days...

Besides the fact MD5 is junk, I am pretty sure this is wrong too.

```
   $password = md5('&password');//remember we hashedpassword before storing last time
```

If you are not sure if you hashed it already, you can count it.

```
 if(strlen($password) == 32) //hashed
```

-Note- This will fail if a user has a password of 32 chars, but that is unlikely.  But md5 is always `32`.  What `'&password'` should be I have no idea.

I would feel remiss if I didn't mention that MD5 and SHA1 (unsalted) can be cracked using online Rainbow tables in about 2 minutes.  So if those passwords ever get exposed/stolen ... lets just say, it's not something you want to risk.